# WSO2 Carbon 4.1.x - how to make the distribution

Tags: wso2

I have checked out the source code, and built it with `mvn clean install`.

Now I'm trying to find out how to build the Carbon 4.1.x distribution (wso2carbon-4.1.0.zip)?

Is there a maven target, something like: `mvn dist:build-bin` that can be run from the root source code folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such special command. If you have built using `mvn clean install` from the carbon kernel source root level, you can find your expected pack at `ROOT/distribution/product/modules/distribution/target/`