# Is Sun/Oracle JDK required to build WSO2 4.1.x?

Tags: wso2

Is **Sun/Oracle JDK** required to build WSO2 4.1.x?

I tried building with **OpenJDK**, but ran into the following issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile 
  (default-compile) on project axis2-transport-testkit: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ... carbon_kernel_4.1.0/dependencies/transports/1.1.0-wso2v8/modules/testkit/
  src/main/java/org/apache/axis2/transport/testkit/doclet/ResourceInfoDoclet.java:[27,22] 
  error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Oracle JDK is required to build Carbon.

Currently Open JDK is not recommended.

Please make sure to use **Oracle JDK 1.6** for building Carbon.

You can use **Oracle JRE 1.7** for running WSO2 products, but there are known issues with compiling the source code with Java 7.

See http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon410/Installation+Prerequisites for additional info.

Comment: That page just states that 1.6 JDK is required.  I couldn't see anything stating that I must use Oracle's JDK and not another JDK such as OpenJDK.

Comment: Yes, That page does not state that Oracle JDK is required. It should be corrected properly.

Comment: This also would be a useful addition to the top level POM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045697/how-to-enforce-a-specific-jdk-vendor-as-a-pre-requisite-of-the-build.  It would have saved me an hour trying when I was trying to figure out why carbon wasn't building for me!

Comment: Hi Chris, The docs team has updated the relevant page. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon410/Installation+Prerequisites