# how to enforce a specific JDK vendor as a pre-requisite of the build?

Tags: maven-3

I am working with some third party code that has dependencies on classes in the `com.sun.javadoc.*` package.  This and some other dependencies mean that the code will only build with **Sun/Oracle JDK**, and not **OpenJDK**.

I don't have an option to remove the dependencies, so I would like the build to fail early and with an easy to understand error message if someone tries to build using a JDK that is not supported.

Is there a way of enforcing the JDK Vendor and JDK Version to be Oracle 1.6 JDK in the pom file?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [carlspring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045796/1033422), I have managed to get this working.  It's not thoroughly tested across all vendors and VM versions, but it's a start.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-property</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireProperty>
              <property>java.vendor</property>
              <message>Java Vendor must be Sun/Oracle.</message>
              <regex>Sun Microsystems Inc\.</regex>
              <regexMessage>Java Vendor must be Sun/Oracle.</regexMessage>
            </requireProperty>
            <requireProperty>
              <property>java.runtime.name</property>
              <message>Java Vendor must be Sun/Oracle.</message>
              <regex>Java\(TM\) SE Runtime Environment</regex>
              <regexMessage>Java Vendor must be Sun/Oracle.</regexMessage>
            </requireProperty>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You know that 1.6 has reached end if life? Besidw from that maybe a unit test may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html) and write your own custom rule.

Comment: Thanks for the link - just seen some guidance at the bottom of the [page](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html) that recommends to use a regex:  "If you would like to enforce a certain vendor string for the JDK, you would use the RequireProperty rule, and check the java.vendor property with a regular expression." - I'll give that a go, as it seems like it may be a little simpler than a custom rule!